# Paypal express checkout API collect billing info

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

Is it possible to collect user billing detail after successful payment how?

Answer (score 0):

You can collect any information you want at any time, but you might be slightly limited based on PayPal features you're using.

For example, if you're using a standard payment button you could setup a form for them to fill out on your return page after they've completed.  There is no guarantee they'll even make it to this page, though, and even if they do they may choose not to fill out your form.  As such, it's generally recommended to collect any necessary data prior to sending the user over to PayPal for payment.

That said, one of the benefits of using PayPal for buyers is that they don't have to fill in forms and don't have to share billing information with you, so you might actually lose sales if you do that.

PayPal will send you an address via IPN (or GetExpressCheckoutDetails, for example) but they only consider that a shipping address.  If I'm working with a system that requires both a billing and a shipping I usually just use that same address for both.